# Update collection of collection using lodash mapreduce

Tags: javascript

I have following collection which i need to send it to datatable and it won't accept collection of collection. So i need to flatten my structure and trying with lodash without much success.

My initial collection

```js
{
    "campaigns": [
      {
        "name": "1st Campaign",
        "campaignType": "Test Campaign",
        "startDate": "2019/04/03",
        "endDate": "2019/04/30",
        "price": 1,
        "books": [
          {
            "title": "\"If They Move . . . Kill 'Em!\"",
            "bookdata": {
              "batch": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "title": "!Click Song",
            "bookdata": {
              "batch": null
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "2nd cam",
        "campaignType": "test type",
        "startDate": "2019/04/10",
        "endDate": "2019/04/10",
        "price": 2.99,
        "retailers": null,
        "comments": null,
        "books": [
          {
            "title": "\"Johnny, We Hardly Knew Ye\"",
            "bookdata": {
              "batch": null
            }
          },
          {
            "title": "'A Very Fine Commander'",
            "bookdata": {
              "batch": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

For each campaign i need structure like following where books title is comma separated for each books under campaign

```js
   {
        "campaigns": [
          {
            "name": "1st Campaign",
            "campaignType": "Test Campaign",
            "startDate": "2019/04/03",
            "endDate": "2019/04/30",
            "price": 1,
            "booksname": "\"If They Move . . . Kill 'Em!\"","!Click Song"
            "books": [
              {
                "title": "\"If They Move . . . Kill 'Em!\"",
                "bookdata": {
                  "batch": 2
                }
              },
              {
                "title": "!Click Song",
                "bookdata": {
                  "batch": null
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "2nd cam",
            "campaignType": "test type",
            "startDate": "2019/04/10",
            "endDate": "2019/04/10",
            "price": 2.99,
            "retailers": null,
            "comments": null,
            "books": [
              {
                "title": "\"Johnny, We Hardly Knew Ye\"",
                "bookdata": {
                  "batch": null
                }
              },
              {
                "title": "'A Very Fine Commander'",
                "bookdata": {
                  "batch": 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: What's your question? What code have you written so far?

Comment: Okay but what have u tried , and what exactly isnt working? Because right now it looks like you want someone to do the work for you since you're only giving us what you got and what u want.

Comment: i have tried _(data.campaigns).flatMap('books').flatMap('title').value() but it do for entire collection and i need to do it for each item and add new property called "booksname" which i can pull from books for each campaign

Comment: I dont understand the difference between the two json you posted. They looks similar to each other. Except booksname which appears on the first object only.

Comment: I want to pick title from books array and add as field in each campaign item

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it using

```
                        data.campaigns.map((item) => {
                            item.Booksname = _.map(item.books, 'title').join(',');
                        })
```